# Attache or Bind UIElement to a CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I've four objects :
    - 1 Canvas (the parent)
    - 1 Ellipse (Child of Canvas)
    - 1 UserControl (Child of the Canvas)
    - 1 CustomControl (Child of the Canvas)

The user can move the UserControl by dragging inside of the canvas.
The Ellipse represent the initial point of my UserControl before the dragging.
Finaly, my CustomControl should draw a line between the UserControl and the Ellipse.

I've tried to bind/Attach my Canvas, the Ellipse and the UserControl to my CustomControl, but it doesn't work.

Any solutions is welcome.

The solution must be simply, but I can't find the solution at the moment.
Thanks.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Canvas x:Name="CanvasTrackObject" Canvas.Left="125" Canvas.Top="95" Background="Aqua">
        <Controls:LineConnector CanvasContainer="{Binding CanvasTrackObject}"
                                Source="{Binding SourcePoint}"
                                Target="{Binding TrackObject}"/>

        <Ellipse x:Name="SourcePoint"
                 Canvas.Left="-5" Canvas.Top="-5" 
                 Width="10" Height="10" Fill="DimGray"/>

        <TestShapes:MainSignal x:Name="TrackObject" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="64"/>

    </Canvas>
```

LineConnector.cs :

```
public class LineConnector : Control 
{ 
  #region Dependency properties

  #region CanvasContainer

  public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasContainerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasContainer", typeof(Canvas), typeof(LineConnector), new PropertyMetadata(default(Canvas)));

  public Canvas CanvasContainer
  {
    get
    {
      return (Canvas)GetValue(CanvasContainerProperty);
    }

    set
    {
      SetValue(CanvasContainerProperty, value);
    }
  }

  #endregion

  #region Source

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(UIElement), typeof(LineConnector), new PropertyMetadata(default(UIElement)));

  public UIElement Source
  {
    get
    {
      return (UIElement)GetValue(SourceProperty);
    }
    set
    {
      SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }
  }

  #endregion

  #region Target

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Target", typeof(UIElement), typeof(LineConnector), new    PropertyMetadata(default(UIElement)));

  public UIElement Target
  {
    get
    {
      return (UIElement)GetValue(TargetProperty);
    }
    set
    {
      SetValue(TargetProperty, value);
    }
  }

  #endregion

  #endregion

  static LineConnector()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LineConnector), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LineConnector)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't data bind from control to control... data bind to custom data properties in between. You can then bind these properties to the `Line.X1`, `Line.X2`, `Line.Y1` and `Line.Y2` properties to create your line.

Comment: I thought it was possible to bind to a control. So, how to retrieve the X and Y positions of the source and the target?

Comment: It *is* possible to bind from a control property to another control property... it's just less suitable in this situation. `X1` and `Y1` can be taken straight from the `Ellipse` and the `X2` and `Y2` values can be taken from the `UserControl` each time it is moved.

Comment: How do you do this ? I've tried to do this but it does'nt work : <Line X1="{Binding ElementName=SourcePoint, Path=Canvas.Left}"
                  Y1="{Binding ElementName=SourcePoint, Path=Canvas.Top}"
                  X2="{Binding ElementName=TrackObject, Path=Canvas.Left}"
                  Y2="{Binding ElementName=TrackObject, Path=Canvas.Top}"/>

Comment: You're still trying to bind to `UIElement`s, not data properties like I suggested. The benefit of binding to data properties is that you can manipulate the code to set just what you want to them... you have no such intermediary control when binding from control to control.

Comment: In fact, I would have wanted to create a stand-alone control who cared to make the connection between two controls.